Nuxt3 chunks missing 404 on Google App Engine deploy
I have an issue deploying a Nuxt3 SSR app on Google App Engine via Github Actions.
Locally, everything builds and runs as expected, both in dev mode with nuxt dev or building and serving with nuxt build then node .output/server/index.mjs as per the docs. The web app is correctly served, accessible locally, and fully interactive.
When deploying via Github Actions to Google App Engine however, all steps of the Github Action succeed, deployment happens and the new GAE instance is running and responding. However, the web app fails to load because many of the JS chunks that the page attempts to load are not found (404). The page loads but is broken since most of the JS is missing.

The weird things I notice :

The pictures and CSS files are all loading fine
SOME of the JS chunks seem to be found as well (see for example DIAUqK2U.js), but I don't see a pattern that could explain why some work and not others.

Here are the steps of my Github Action release.yaml :
on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - 'staging' # Trigger on every push to staging branch
    tags:
      - 'v*' # Trigger on every tag push starting with 'v'

  # Build
  build:
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging'
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: read
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      # Env file for staging deploy
      - name: Copy env file for dev
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging'
        run: cp env/.staging.env .env
      # Env file for production deploy
      - name: Copy env file for prod
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
        run: cp env/.prod.env .env

      - name: Build package
        run: npm run build
      
      # Upload build artifacts (to use in deploy job)
      - name: Upload compiled packages artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: front-build-artifacts
          path: |
            .output/
            .env
          retention-days: 1

  # App Engine deploy
  deploy:
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging'
    name: App Engine Deploy
    needs: [build]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: read
      id-token: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Download build artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: front-build-artifacts

      - name: List files
        run: ls -la

      - name: List .output/public/_nuxt
        run: ls -la .output/public/_nuxt
      
      - name: cat INDEX
        run: cat .output/server/index.mjs
      
      - name: cat RUNTIME
        run: cat .output/server/chunks/runtime.mjs

      # STAGING App engine deploy
      - name: Authenticate with Google Cloud on dev environment
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2' # https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth
        with:
          credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_DEV_KEY }}

      - name: App engine deploy on dev environment
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging'
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-appengine@v2 # https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-app-engine
        with:
          project_id: XXXXXXX
          deliverables: 'app.yaml'

My app.yaml :
runtime: nodejs20

instance_class: F1

handlers:
  # Anything under /_nuxt folder
  - url: /_nuxt
    static_dir: .output/public
    expiration: 97d
    secure: always

  # _ipx prefixed medias handled by Nuxt server
  - url: /(_ipx)(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt|webp|webm))$
    script: auto
    secure: always
  
  # All other medias (pics, videos, txt)
  - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt|webp|webm))$
    static_files: .output/public/\1
    upload: .output/public/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt|webp|webm)$
    expiration: 97d
    secure: always

  # Everything else => handled by Nuxt server
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301

env_variables:
  HOST: '0.0.0.0'

automatic_scaling:
  min_instances: 0
  max_instances: 1
  min_idle_instances: 0
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.8
  target_throughput_utilization: 0.8
  max_concurrent_requests: 50
  min_pending_latency: 50ms
  max_pending_latency: automatic

Note : I have added the ls cat cat steps in order to have an idea of the output.
Output of ls -la .output/public/_nuxt from the Github Action, which contains many generated chunks :
total 4408
drwxr-xr-x 3 runner docker   12288 Apr 25 14:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 runner docker    4096 Apr 25 14:41 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 1110815 Apr 25 14:41 3KWQAHCS.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker    5067 Apr 25 14:41 3RB7eywz.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker    1388 Apr 25 14:41 3nNXCWwn.js
......

The output of cat .output/server/chunks/runtime.mjs from the Github Action contains mappings for each of these :
...
 "/_nuxt/BocX5zAU.js": {
    "type": "text/javascript; charset=utf-8",
    "etag": "\"1b1f-65gnyxC/4PZzz9c3izrpbyDveps\"",
    "mtime": "2024-04-25T14:39:04.637Z",
    "size": 6943,
    "path": "../public/_nuxt/BocX5zAU.js"
  },
...

Issue : the chunks requested by the page served by GAE do not exist in these lists of chunks actually available. There seems to be a mismatch, and the ones requested by the web app are nowhere to be found.
What I imagine could be going wrong here :

Mistake on my end in the build, not generating the chunks in the correct folder ?
Mistake on my end in the app.yaml telling the app engine where to find the _nuxt/ chunks ?
Mistake somewhere in the Github Action in generated, copying and serving the files ?
Error in Google App Engine serving the NuxtJS app and/or the chunks ?
Cache issue of Google App Engine not finding the new chunks ?

Also, is it expected that the generated chunks have a different hashed name on my local machine and on the server ?
